# How to reference a service-stack Web Service from Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, servicestack

I have implemented various Web Services using ServiceStack and now I want to expose them to Crystal Reports.  Initially, creating a "Service" data source and pointing it at the running URL, nothing is returned.  I assume this is because none of my POCOs are adorned with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes.

Ideally I'd like to avoid this. One of the nice things about ServiceStack is that one merely writes a POCO and voila, everything *just works*.  Now that the data my have to be exposed to Crystal Reports, does this mean I have to adorn all these POCOs just to get it to work, or am I perhaps missing something else?

Comment: I don't have Crystal in front of me to test, but could it be that you're getting back json instead of xml? (/myService?format=xml) Edit: Come to think of it, I think Crystal makes a SOAP request.

Comment: @EricW, it is JSON by default, but I am not sure if Crystal will let me specify `accept/xml`.  I did manage to hook it up to the soap11/12 services by changing all the requests to `Post` (crystal evidently doesn't like RESTful APIs), and although it could then see the services, I was unable to use them (nothing in object browser, unable to bind to them).  Thanks for your time :)